# How to associate line number from a file to the side by side diff output result file?

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, files, diff

My scenario is that:

First generate side by side `diff` of two files using:

```
diff -y --supress-common-lines file1.txt file2.txt > DiffResult.txt
```

Output of `DiffResult.txt`:

```
   file1.txt             file2.txt
This is line A    |   This is line B
This is line C    |   This is line D
```

Now lets say the line

```
This is line A
```

and

```
This is line B
```

are in line 5 of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` respectively. Then I should be able to associate the appropriate line number to it as follows:

Desired output of `DiffResult.txt`:

```
      file1.txt                file2.txt
5   This is line A    |  5   This is line B
7   This is line C    |  7   This is line D
```

The reason why I am going for this approach is because if I generate line numbers before `diff`, then even for a small white space change, the `diff` would show a difference because of the line numbers associated with the lines.

Anyone with bright ideas? I think this is the toughest question that has ever been asked in StackExchange, I believe :D

Comment: use commands like `nl` to add lines numbers to your input file and then pass onto `diff`.. and whats with snide remarks in question?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, if i generate line numbers before (using nl or any other command) and pass it to diff, for any space changes, the diff will be shown which i don't want to happen.

Comment: can you show example input files where pre-processing to add line numbers will result in that behavior, by default `diff` will report even whitespace mismatches.. and either way, see `man diff` and use options to ignore white-space mismatches being reported in output

Comment: Even if you use ignore white spaces, the displacement caused by white spaces or newlines will show change in line numbers right so diff will fail in this case.

Comment: again, you are only saying so and so would happen without giving an example to back up your claims... if you give example input files with all your corner cases, someone would be able to suggest some solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved by filtering the output of `diff`.  This example works for me (though the placement and size of the gutter between left/right sides of the diff output are likely to be a detail that differs between implementations):

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: diff-two-column,v 1.2 2016/09/26 20:38:32 tom Exp $
# see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312025/how-to-associate-line-number-from-a-file-to-the-side-by-side-diff-output-result

usage() {
    cat >&2 <<EOF
usage: $0 file1 file2
EOF
    exit 1
}

[ $# = 2 ] || usage
[ -f "$1" ] || usage
[ -f "$2" ] || usage

width=${COLUMNS:-80}
check=$(stty size|cut -d' ' -f2)
[ -n "$check" ] && width=$check

diff -W $width -y "$1" "$2" | \
expand | \
awk -v width=$width '
BEGIN {
    L=0;
    R=0;
    gutter = width / 2;
    half = gutter - 2;
}
{
    textL = substr($0, 1, half - 1);
    sub("[ ]+$", "", textL);  # trim trailing blanks

    # The script relies on correctly extracting textM, the gutter:
    # if lines differ,    textM is " ! "
    # if line inserted,   textM is " > "
    # if line deleted,    textM is " < "
    # if lines unchanged, textM is "   "
    textM = substr($0, gutter - 2, 3);

    textR = ( length($0) > gutter ) ? substr($0, gutter+1, half) : "";

    if ( textM != " > " ) {
         L++;
    }
    if ( textM != " < " ) {
         R++;
    }

    if ( textL != textR ) {
        # printf "SHOW %s\n", $0;
        # printf "gap \"%s\"\n", textM;
        # printf "<<< \"%s\"\n", textL;
        # printf ">>> \"%s\"\n", textR;
        if ( textL == "" ) {
            printf "%5s %-*s %-3s %5d %s\n",
                " ", half, textL,
                textM,
                R, textR;
        } else if ( textR == "" ) {
            printf "%5d %-*s %-3s %5s %s\n",
                L, half, textL,
                textM,
                " ", textR;
        } else {
            printf "%5d %-*s %-3s %5d %s\n",
                L, half, textL,
                textM,
                R, textR;
        }
    } else {
        # printf "SKIP %s\n", $0;
    }
}
'
```

You cannot add line numbers *before* `diff`, because if there are insertions or deletions, the line numbers starting at that point will not match, making the differences not useful.  My script computes the line numbers for the left/right sides of the difference in the awk script:

- It first decides how wide to make the diff, based on the width of the terminal.
- There is (in GNU diff 3.2 which I tested) a *gutter* (unused space) in the middle of the side-by-side differences.  Starting with an 80-column terminal, I determined a way to compute the position of the gutter.
- After initializing, the script extracts from each line (in `awk`, this is `$0`) the left (`textL`) and right (`textR`) strings, and tests if they are empty (which would happen if there were an insert/delete).
- If the left/right lines are different, the script reconstructs the `diff` output, but adding the line-numbers.

Given this on the left

```
1
2
3
4
This is line A
6
This is line C
123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.

yyy
```

and this on the right

```
1
2
3
4
This is line B
6
This is line D
abcdefghi.abcdefghi.abcdefghi.abcdefghi.abcdefghi.
xxx
```

(10 lines on the left, 9 on the right), this script produces

```
    5 This is line A                          |      5 This is line B
    7 This is line C                          |      7 This is line D
    8 123456789.123456789.123456789.1234567   |      8 abcdefghi.abcdefghi.abcdefghi.abcdefg
                                              |      9 xxx
   10 yyy                                     <
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the response. Can you explain for me what is the logic behind the snippet ? Is there any shortcut other than this ? :D

Comment: I noticed that it didn't handle blank lines - here's an update with example.  You may find it helpful to uncomment the printf's which show details.

Comment: Only 1 upvote for this? +1,000 @Thomas